# Internet access point pecularities

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, internet

So I just had this really weird problem come up. I have this really weird setup because of a few factors.

1. My TV/Internet arrive via the same ethernet.
2. The TV part is very finicky when it comes to how it's connected.
3. A small part of my home is not covered by the main router because of too many obstructions.

This results in the following situation - I have to use an old router to cover the room where the main one doesn't reach. The TV part is very finicky - if the network cable is plugged in to the WAN port of the router the TV refuses to work.

Now here is the really weird bit: If plugged in the LAN ports, the TV works. Only then the laptop cannot access the internet(you'd say, for obvious reasons). The thing is though - all my handhelds CAN(they're all android devices btw).
When I enter the web admin interface, naturally it says that the WAN port is unplugged. And yet, my tablet(which is wifi only, so you couldn't say it's auto-switching to mobile data) can browse the internet no problem at all - why is that? And if that's possible, how can I get the laptop(Win7) to work too?
**The goal here being to find out why the laptop does not have internet access.**

The router in question is TP-Link TL-WR740N. And I have enabled all pass-throughs and disabled its firewall and anything that might interfere with additional stuff passing through(the TV packets or however they deliver it) in an attempt to let the TV pass through, but to no avail.

Edit:
Network diagram below
[image: Be right back.]

The additional router is between switch2 and STB4 and is set up as described above.

Comment: Why can the laptop not access the internet? Which router and which port is that plugged in to? How are the two routers connected to each other?

Comment: laptop ipconfig and traceroute/pathping information might be useful here as would connection information from a functional system. A network diagram would be *glorious*. From experience when connecting from router to router, except when double-natting, connecting lan port to lan port is what I'd do

Comment: And I have included the diagram you requested. Hopefully this will help.